# How to use BindingUtils with style properties (uses the setStyle method)?

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, binding

Most examples of `BindingUtils` shows how to bind a property (either a public variable or a getter/setter) of an object at runtime.

But how do I go about to bind a property, such as `"top"` of a component, when it's only accessible via the `setStyle("top", value);` at runtime?

Should I just create a custom pair of getters/setters to affect the style properties of the UIComponent in question? Seems a bit unnecessary...

Answer (score 1):

You should bind the property you want to watch with a "setter", i.e. a function :

```
private function foo():void
{
    BindingUtils.bindSetter(makeStyleSetter("styleName", target), this, "styleProperty");
}

private function makeStyleSetter(style:String, target:UIComponent):Function
{
    return function(value:Object):void
    {
        target.setStyle(style, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: On the Memory management side of things, should I store a reference of the returned 'ChangeWatcher' instance from the BindingUtils.bindSetter(...) call? So that way I can later call .unwatch(); on it to get rid of the solid reference? (I imagine it's not a weak reference :S)

Comment: Also, I think you would need Function Closures (local variables to keep the scope of the target UIComponent) to prevent some incorrect references problems. At least, in this context... if the target can potentially change that is. http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/10/08/function-closures-and-this-in-actionscript-3/

Comment: Yup, you can store a reference of the ChangeWatcher. But I think the function closures stuff you're speaking of is not relevant here : you don't do anything scope-related in the dynamic function.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right. I'm doing some investigation on Function Closures and sure enough, if you pass an argument, it doesn't replace or break the reference. It got me motivated to write a little blog about'em things! :)